# iOS iBooks like store animation

Tags: ios4, transition, modalviewcontroller, ibooks

Anyone know how Apple does the transition to the store in the iBooks app?  I know they are using a Modal View Controller with the UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal transition style set but I don't see how they are showing the "depth" of the "bookcase" when they do the transition.

Comment: I'd like to know how they do this too. My best guess is that there is some sort of OpenGL involved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing that the animation works something like this:

1. A 'snapshot' image is taken of the
   bookshelf and set to the contents of
   a CALayer.
2. The bookshelf view is
   removed from its superview.
3. The newly created CALayer (the bookshelf
   layer) with the image of the
   bookshelf is added to the layer of
   some existing (or newly created)
   UIView
4. Another layer (the side
   layer) is created and an image of
   the side of the bookshelf is used as
   its contents.  This layer is added
   to the UIView The side layer is
   positioned at the right edge of the
   bookshelf layer.
5. The side layer's
   transform is set to rotate it M_PI_2
   rads about the y-axis.  This
   essentially makes it invisible as it
   is perpendicular to the device
   screen
6. The bookshelf and side layers
   have an animation added to them that
   transforms each with an M_PI_2
   rotation about the y axis.  At the
   conclusion of this animation, the
   bookshelf will be perpendicular to
   the device screen and the side layer
   will be fully in view.
7. A new layer (the store layer) is created and a snapshot image of the store is added as the contents of the new layer, it is transformed and positioned so that it will appear correctly when . . .
8. The side layer and store layer have an animation added that transforms each with an M_PI_2 rotation about the y axis.
9. All of the layers are removed and the store UIView is displayed.

I don't have any inside knowledge of the iBooks app, but if I were trying to duplicate this effect, this is how I'd go about it. FWIW, once you get the hang of positioning and transforming the CALayers, its kinda fun to mess around with animations like this.